# Server Error in '/' Application. Error in vb.net

Tags: url, web-config, vb.net-2010

After hosting when i run the application am getting error like above. but that application  worked on local machine with out any error.

```
web config file


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="server=10.103.1.166;User Id=root;database=test;password=test123" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<!--<add name="testConnectionString" connectionString="server=10.103.200.138;User Id=root;database=test;password=test123" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>-->
    <!--'LDAP://servername/ou=ouname,dc=domain,dc=com-->
    <add name="ADConnection" connectionString="LDAP://sunbs.in:389/ou=sunbs,DC=sunbs,DC=in"/>
    <!--<add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain1.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain1,DC=test,DC=com" />-->
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <!--<membership >
  <providers >
    <add name="NetForgeMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnection" connectionUsername="sbsldap" connectionPassword="sbs@123" />
  </providers>
</membership>-->
    <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,         System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnection" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>

<customErrors  mode="Off "></customErrors>
<!--<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>-->


 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can I correct the error?

```
error description

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

Comment: Is there really an expectation that someone can tell you why you get an ISE from looking at XML configuration without the actual error?

Comment: Look in the Server's Event Viewer >> Windows Logs >> Application. Look for the ASP.NET exception that is thrown to get more information on the problem. Full exception information will be available within the event viewer.

Comment: @jordanm sorry what did u say? i cant understand

Comment: No not the web.config code, show the error description

Comment: @klenkie to get a eventviewer where should i go?

Comment: Simple Open Run window and type there `eventvwr` and hit enter

Comment: @yograj Gupta in cmd prompt ah?